# Dynamically changing file lock/access permissions on open file

Tags: winapi, sharepoint

I have a client application where we try to check files in and out from SharePoint for editing.  I am using SharePoint's SOAP interfaces and some FrontPage interfaces to do this.  It used to work fine under SharePoint 2007, but with 2010 I can't check out or check in a file if I have the file open for editing.  I get a message like "FileXXX is locked for exclusive use by DOMAIN\user" when I examine the returned error message.  I also cannot update any of the user defined SharePoint fields for a file/list if the file is open for editing.

My question is this:  Is there a way to change the access/lock for an open file to make it non-exclusive temporarily and then restore it?

Note: Some of my data files are opened using windows file handles (flat files) and others are opened using windows structured  storage (compound document files).

Answer (score 1):

This may not work for Sharepoint specifically, but the ReOpenFile() API does what you want. I don't know of any other way to do this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365497(v=vs.85).aspx